# Jquery google map plugin with geolocation

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using jquery google map's plugin [link](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/) for a project
My main goal is to load with markers and if a user clicks on a link it will display a circle with his location
As I have start feeling the map with markers i don't know the their coords so Iam initializing 
the map and adding markers with bounds=true

Comment: Did you extend the gmap plugin with the getCurrentPosition function as per the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to make an extension for the getCurrentPosition function as per the documentation.

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/wiki/Examples#Example_get_user_position

> First, create a file called jquery.ui.map.extensions.js. Paste this
>   code and save the file, you should minify the javascript before you
>   use it in production:

http://jsfiddle.net/X5r8r/398/

Here's the extension in the top. For some reason I got an error with the _trigger function from the plugin so I edited the callback out and added the addmarker.

Comment: I have included the  jquery.ui.map.extensions.js file, you can see it on the reference manage resources , and it works great. If you try to find you location in the map manually, after clicking the link,using zoom in and zoom out works great.
My problem is that after clicking I want to zoom and "bound" on the geolacated marker

Comment: Okay, then you'll need to do something like $("#mapcont").gmap('getMap').setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng)) to center the map. I'm not sure what you mean by bound on the new area.

Comment: I mean that after the user is geolocated with the click the map, will be focused on his position, something like [http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-geolocation.html](http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-geolocation.html) 
I have tried your code but it does not seem to work
[http://jsfiddle.net/theodore/X5r8r/399/](http://jsfiddle.net/theodore/X5r8r/399/)